# "Is to lie" or "is lie"

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitives

> His kidneys become infected and the antibiotics they administer cause allergic reactions. Sometimes he is so close to death all I can do **is lie** with him and **share** his suffering.

The sentences stated above have been taken from a story named **Your son is in a coma** published in Reader's Digest, January 2006. I cannot find the name of the author of this story.

Is there any **that** which has been omitted? In my opinion we need to use **that** after **so close to death**, or we could use an **and** with a comma before ***all I need is lie..***. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If I wrote ***all I can do is laying with him and sharing his suffering*** or ***all I can do is to lie with him and to share his suffering*** instead of original version that the writer wrote , will it be wrong? If it is wrong, please tell why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To help one better understand the correct use of lie/lay, I recommend the brief notes and especially the chart at http://freeology.com/grammar/lie-lay-practice-worksheet/

Reviewing the chart will show you why

> **"all I can do is laying with him and sharing his suffering"** is incorrect

and why

> **"all I can do is to lie with him and to share his suffering"** is correct.

You are also correct that the omitted "that," while optional, would also be appropriate usage.

Answer (score 0):

In OP's example usage, ***lie*** and ***share*** are *infinitive* verb forms, where the explicit "infinitive marker" ***to*** is optional.

In practice most native speakers probably wouldn't include the infinitive marker before *either* verb, but there no grammatical rule requiring this (note, however, that only using it on the *second* verb would be stylistically appalling).

I should also point out that to avoid confusion with ***lie*** = utter falsehoods, ***lay*** [down] would be better. Also - continuous verb forms don't work well in contexts like this.

Comment: Please tell me when and where continuous verb forms work well.

Comment: *I've no idea if it helps or not. All I **am doing** is **laying/lying** beside him and **sharing** his suffering*.

Comment: I would avoid using "lay with him" all by itself as well.  "Lay down with" would probably be better if you were going to use that.  "Lay with" on its own can mean "to have sex with" in some contexts.

Comment: @Tofystedeth Agreed, though at least it refers to lying down on the same  bed. In a hospital context, when you are in the same room, it might be better to say "all I can do is **stay** with him" .

Comment: Hey, @FumbleFingers, are you still banging around right this moment? It's 22.10 in the evening, your time, and I'd like to chat with you about something.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: At about 22.10 last night I was jumping about punching the air and shouting *Yes! Vindicated!* I was watching [a fascinating debate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A620t61OTc8&t=1312s) on extinctions, from which it seemed clear the prevailing current scientific view is that homo sap *actively exterminated* any other hominids they co-existed with (incl. neanderthals). I'd been saying this for over 40 years, but other people always brushed it aside, saying we just "outcompeted" them for resources. Yeah, right! Ignore our obvious proclivity for genocide even today.

Comment: I'd have thought it was obvious that we exterminated the Neaderthals through both action AND out-competition.  But obviously some of us got really chummy with Neanderthals -- since we sport some of their DNA. If you got a moment, can you find the chatroom Chat with Cyberherbalist?  I have some news and a couple of questions for you!

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: Hi, my man! I've just returned here after raising [the morality of recreating Neanderthals](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/33021/) on philopsophy.SE. I can't find the chatroom you mentioned, but I'm around for at least the next couple of hours. Then AFK for a couple of hours, after which I'll be (spasmodically) around again for another six hours or so (my diurnal rhythm doesn't match my geographical location very accurately! :) What's on your mind?

Comment: Try this one: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37025/chat-with-cyberherbalist  It's in ELU chat.